# SQL Function Get Column By Reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, where-in

Let's say there are 3 tables: Genders, Countries and Users. Users has among others a column named Gender and also a column named Country.

I want to add a new entry to Users and select one of the columns Male/Female {M, F} and a country from the rows of Countries dynamically just for testing purposes.

```
insert into dbo.[Users] (Gender, UserName, Country)
  select Genders.Male, 'newbie', Countries.(the one which matches column CountryId) FROM Genders, Countries
```

I want to achieve this: **'M', 'newbie'**, MyCountry

After applying the suggestion from 'zip' I get the result ***2 rows affected***, same number as the external tables I'm referencing. The Query added 2 rows, **so I guess I am missing the WHERE conditions.**

The Genders Table is meant as a Property and will have only one row that I manually added.

```
Table Genders; 1 row
Male : uniqueidentifier
Female : uniqueidentifier
```

Countries is a table with many rows, so I want to select one matching the criteria of one of it's column values, say the value of column CountryId.

Comment: insert into dbo.[Users] (Gender, UserName)
  select Genders.Male, 'newbie' from Genders                      You need to specify which table Genders.Male comes from by adding "from Genders"

Comment: There's no `FROM` clause that introduces `genders`. And no `WHERE` as well. But with that limited information you gave it's hard to give a more precise answer on how you can achieve what you want. [Edit] the question and include a [example], i.e. the related tables as `CREATE` statement, sample data as `INSERT` statements and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: What's the schema of `Genders`?

Comment: @zip The result is (3 rows affected). That is exactly the number of external tables I am referencing  ( FROM Gender, Countries, UserStatuses)

Comment: I edited the question. @EricBrandt It has only one Row meant as a Property, They actually are in uniqueidentifier datatype, same as the Gender column in Users.

Comment: In the comments, here and below, you've changed the question to now include three tables, and things are only getting more confused instead of clearer. Have a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), as well as the link in @stickybit's comment. What you're trying to do seems fairly simple, but we don't have enough information to provide any meaningful help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuored the solution out. Thank you all who responded for pointing me in the right direction.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Users] (Gender, UserName, Country)
  SELECT Genders.Male, 'newbie', Countries.CountryId 
    FROM Genders, Countries
       WHERE Countries.ISO2 = '##'
```

'##' = 2 letter ISO of country.

Explanation:
1. `INSERT INTO dbo.[Users]` = Add a new row to Table "Users"
2. `(Gender, UserName, Country)` = Includes the columns in table "Users". If a column is not specified and it had a property of not allowing Nulls, an exception would be thrown!
3. `FROM Genders, Countries` = Include the external tables associated to look for
4. `WHERE Countries.ISO2 = '##'` = This condition allows you to precisely select which column of which row you seek. So I searched for a certain row where a column named ISO2 had a value '##' and looked then for the CountryId value in the same row (entry). There may be cases when multiple rows have identical value so you would have to further specify the conditions by using AND or OR oeprators.

When a table does not contain more than 1 row, I should not have to apply WHERE Conditions. It will select the default one existing. But because the Countries Table had multiple items (3 Rows), leaving the WHERE clause out, caused to add 3 times the same User, with each row having a distinct CountryId!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random value using:

```
insert into dbo.[Users] (Gender, UserName)
  select top (1) g.Male, 'newbie'
  from Genders.Male
  order by newid();
```

Comment: The **top (1)** keyword doesn't seem to work if not next to **select**. I have 3 cases of referencing external tables. What do you suggest?

Comment: @user123581321 . . . I suggest that you ask a *new* question.  This answers the question that you actually asked  here.